# Custom font not working at runtime in Android

Tags: android, customization, textview, custom-font

I made a custom TextView to load font (in my case it is [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) font). My custom TextView class looks as below:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("NewApi")
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    /**
     * Load and apply font for this widget
     *
     * @param context to initialize
     */
    private void init(Context context) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "icomoon.ttf");
        if(font != null)
            setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

In my layout file, I used this class as below:

```
<com.test.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_about_hotel_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="&#xe020;"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />
```

Everything goes well when I use this class in layout and set text to display a font icon. Now the problem begins when I try to use this class in my Activity class to set the font icon as below:

```
CustomTextView txtHotelIcon = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_about_hotel_icon);
txtHotelIcon.setText("&#xe020;");
```

Now the problem is, if I set the font character in XML layout, it works great and font icon is visible. But when I try to set this font text value at run-time, it shows the exact text instead of showing font icon.

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the `TextView` doesn't support the HTML notation directly, so you could try one of the following:

- Load your text using `setText(Html.fromHtml("&#xe020;"))`
- Replace the HTML notation with Unicode `setText("\uE020")`

Haven't tried those with icon fonts yet, so they might not work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Html.fromHtml works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use another format at code

```
CustomTextView txtHotelIcon = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_about_hotel_icon);
txtHotelIcon.setText("\ue020");
```